Parallel Execution with multiprocessing.Pool Slower than Sequential in Raster Data Processing
I'm working on a Python program that processes raster data using rasterio and parallelism with multiprocessing.Pool. The goal is to extract multiple crops from a large raster mosaic based on particle positions. Here's the code I'm using:
import rasterio
import multiprocessing
import heapq
import random
import time
from functools import lru_cache
from rasterio.windows import Window

NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 4
CROP_PX_SIZE = 384
PARTICLES_NUMBER = 1000
MOSAIC_PATH = 'path_to_mosaic.tif'

def get_crops(particles_positions):
    crops_by_particles = []
    with multiprocessing.Pool(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS) as pool:
      pool.starmap(worker, [(particle_position, crops_by_particles) for particle_position in particles_positions])
    return list(crops_by_particles)

def worker(particle_position, crops_by_particles):
    crop = get_map_crop_for_particle_position(particle_position)
    heapq.heappush(crops_by_particles, (particle_position, crop))

def get_map_crop_for_particle_position(particle_position):
    mosaic = get_mosaic()

    row_off_px, col_off_px = rasterio.transform.rowcol(mosaic.transform, particle_position[0], particle_position[1])
    row_off_px = row_off_px - (CROP_PX_SIZE // 2)
    col_off_px = col_off_px - (CROP_PX_SIZE // 2)
    crop_window = Window(col_off_px, row_off_px, CROP_PX_SIZE, CROP_PX_SIZE)
    return mosaic.read(window=crop_window)

@lru_cache()
def get_mosaic():
      return rasterio.open(MOSAIC_PATH)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lat = -3.7
    lon = 40.2
    error = 0.001
    particles = [(random.gauss(lat, error), random.gauss(lon, error)) for _ in range(PARTICLES_NUMBER)]
    start_time = time.time()
    get_crops(particles)
    end_time = time.time()
    execution_time_ms = (end_time - start_time) * 1000
    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time_ms:.2f} ms")

The program runs slower in parallel compared to sequential execution. Even when I run it in parallel the result is much worse with 8 threads than with 4. Also with 4 it is worse than with 2, etc. This behavior is unexpected because parallelism should improve performance for independent tasks.

After some debugging, I suspect that the issue might be related to
how rasterio.open is handled:

I'm using @lru_cache on get_mosaic() to avoid reopening the mosaic multiple times, but I suspect this doesn't work well with multiprocessing.


Is the placement of rasterio.open causing inefficiencies? My understanding is that it should be called within each worker to ensure independent file handles.
Is the use of shared objects (crops_by_particles) in combination with heapq problematic? Should I use another mechanism to collect results?
Are there any best practices for using multiprocessing with non-serializable objects like rasterio.DatasetReader?
Any advice on identifying and resolving the bottleneck would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

The @lru_cache decorator does not work well with multiprocessing, as each child process creates its own memory copy (due to forking), and the file is not shared correctly. This means that each process attempts to open the file again, which can be expensive. A better practice would be to open the file within each worker, ensuring that each process handles its own instance of the file. While this may not fully resolve the issue, it could help improve performance.

multiprocessing very, very often -- if not downright usually -- makes things worse rather than better. Don't use it unless you've analyzed how data needs to move through your system (how expensive is deserialization? how expensive is deserialization? how expensive is copying the argument to the child? how expensive is copying the returned result to the parent?) -- and determined that you have no better choice. (The usual better choice is to delegate heavy lifting to a C library that doesn't need to hold the GIL, if in fact you're CPU-bound and need it at all in the first place).

"parallelism should improve performance for independent tasks" - that's true, if the tasks are truly independent and if splitting up the work into independent tasks doesn't add more work than it saves (for example because each task now needs to do something independently that only had to be done once when it was all one job)

Your script has get_crops(particles), which is supposed to return a list. If you were to actually look at what was being returned it would be an empty list. get_crops is passing to each worker function the empty list crops_by_particles but each pool process receives a copy of that list to which it is appending data. The original ``crops_by_particles` instance in the main process never gets updated.

Your code has both I/O operations and CPU-bound operations. Currently, you are using a multiprocessing pool for doing both I/O and CPU processing and this requires your worker function to open up and read data. Whether this re-opening in each process is a costly operation is not clear. What is clear is that your code as posted cannot possibly work because your worker function is performing a heapq.heappush operation on a copy of a list owned by the main process (see my comment to your post). Even if the heappush operations were being performed on some shareable list, adding an object to a heap is not an atomic operation and you would need to serialize it by using a lock.
There is overhead in creating a multiprocessing pool and passing data to and from child processes. If the savings achieved by running your worker function in parallel is not sufficient to overcome this additional overhead, then you should just do serial processing and forget about a multiprocessing solution. But what I would try is as follows. Create both a multithreading pool and a multiprocessing pool. Your worker function will be running within the multithreading pool but will be passed the multiprocessing pool that it can use for performing the CPU-bound operations. The file will have been opened once by the main thread. Now it is not clear whether a mosaic.read call can be performed concurrently by multiple threads using the same opened file. The code below assumes that it can. If you cannot, then the main thread should be doing the reading and you will want to use the second approach below.
DISCLAIMER: I am not in a position to test this having no access to your data (and frankly not knowing anything about rasterio), so you may need some code adjustments to get this to work.
First Approach Assuming We Can Safely Do Concurrent mosaic.read Operations
import rasterio
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
from functools import partial
import heapq
import random
import time
from rasterio.windows import Window

NUMBER_OF_WORKERS = 4
CROP_PX_SIZE = 384
PARTICLES_NUMBER = 1000
MOSAIC_PATH = 'path_to_mosaic.tif'

def get_crops(particles_positions):
    crops_by_particles = []
    with Pool(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS) as multiprocessing_pool, \
        ThreadPool(NUMBER_OFWORKERS) as multithreading_pool:
        mosaic = rasterio.open(MOSAIC_PATH)
        worker = partial(get_crop_window, mosaic, multiprocessing_pool)
        for idx, crop in enumerate(multithreading_pool.imap(worker, particles_positions)):
            heapq.heappush(crops_by_particles, (particles_positions[idx], crop))
    return crops_by_particles

def get_crop_window(mosaic, multiprocessing_pool, particle_position):
    crop_window = multiprocessing_pool.apply(get_map_crop_for_particle_position, args=(particle_position,))
    return mosaic.read(window=crop_window)

def get_map_crop_for_particle_position(particle_position):
    row_off_px, col_off_px = rasterio.transform.rowcol(mosaic.transform, particle_position[0], particle_position[1])
    row_off_px = row_off_px - (CROP_PX_SIZE // 2)
    col_off_px = col_off_px - (CROP_PX_SIZE // 2)
    return Window(col_off_px, row_off_px, CROP_PX_SIZE, CROP_PX_SIZE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lat = -3.7
    lon = 40.2
    error = 0.001
    particles = [(random.gauss(lat, error), random.gauss(lon, error)) for _ in range(PARTICLES_NUMBER)]
    start_time = time.time()
    get_crops(particles)
    end_time = time.time()
    execution_time_ms = (end_time - start_time) * 1000
    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time_ms:.2f} ms")

Second Approach
If reads cannot be performed concurrently, we are back to using a single, multiprocessing pool and the main process is performing all of the I/O in addition to the heap operations. We now need to update two functions as follows. Even if concurrent reads work, i.e. the first approach, you may get better performance doing these reads serially using this second approach; it will depend on your disk hardware.
def get_crops(particles_positions):
    from functools import partial

    def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize

    crops_by_particles = []
    with Pool(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS) as pool:
        mosaic = rasterio.open(MOSAIC_PATH)
        chunksize = compute_chunksize(PARTICLES_NUMBER, NUMBER_OF_WORKERS)
        worker = partial(get_map_crop_for_particle_position, mosaic)
        for idx, crop_window in enumerate(
            pool.imap(worker, particles_positions, chunksize=chunksize)
        ):
            crop = mosaic.read(window=crop_window)
            heapq.heappush(crops_by_particles, (particles_positions[idx], crop))
    return crops_by_particles

def get_map_crop_for_particle_position(mosaic, particle_position):
    row_off_px, col_off_px = rasterio.transform.rowcol(mosaic.transform, particle_position[0], particle_position[1])
    row_off_px = row_off_px - (CROP_PX_SIZE // 2)
    col_off_px = col_off_px - (CROP_PX_SIZE // 2)
    return Window(col_off_px, row_off_px, CROP_PX_SIZE, CROP_PX_SIZE)


I'm sorry but your code contains multiple errors (e.g. you call particle_positions but the variable is particles_positions, you call mosaic.transform without it being received by arguments or available, etc). However, I have run a fixed version of both versions and none of them can beat the sequential version. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

I didn't really think that get_map_crop_for_particle_position would be sufficiently CPU-intensive to make multiprocessing worthwhile. But, except for the couple of typos that you were forced to correct, I believe this did answer your question in the sense that if anything was going to work (your multiprocessing code could not possibly be correct), one of the above approaches would be it.

My question was not related to the code not working, but to the speed of serial or parallel computation. Even if the returned list is empty, the code serves as an example since the computation is still going to be done. Anyway, you can assume that the list is returned complete, that won't change the execution times at all.
